# How to display Xpath on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xpath, ios5, html-parsing

I'm trying to extract the weather information from [here](http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=KBFM&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most%20recent%20only&submitmet=Submit) using Xpath on the iPhone. As of now it parses all the data but I'm stuck on how to extract the content and display it in a table.
This is what I have so far:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ @"http://aviationweather.gov/adds/metars/?station_ids=1234&std_trans=translated&chk_metars=on&hoursStr=most+recent+only&submitmet=Submit"stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"1234" withString:self.title]]];

TFHpple * doc       = [[TFHpple alloc] initWithHTMLData:data];
NSArray * elements  = [doc searchWithXPathQuery:@"//table[1]//tr"];
NSLog(@"%@", elements);
TFHppleElement * element = [elements objectAtIndex:0];
[element content];              // Tag's innerHTML
[element  tagName];              // "a"
[element  attributes];           // NSDictionary of href, class, id, etc.
[element  objectForKey:@"href"]; // Easy access to single attribute
```

If anybody needs to see what its outputting so far, let me know.

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Take a look on Google for "UITableView tutorial", e.g. http://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=uitableview+tutorial&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8

Comment: Its not the displaying the table that I don't understand, its organizing the data so that I can display it. Thanks though

Comment: I guess I don't understand. What data do you want to show? If you can put your data into an array, then you can put it into a table. And it looks like you already have that array in `elements`, and it's just a matter of looping through your array to make table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue I got to the point your at and didn't no where to go but I end up implementing this code. Hope it helps there is still little bits need to make it work correctly but do to the nature of the app I have developed this is all I can give you. its not much more its just the actual implementation into your code that you need really.

```
#import "XPathQuery.h"


NSMutableArray *weatherArray = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:0]retain]; // Initilize the NSMutableArray can also be done with just an NSArray but you will have to change the populateArray method.
NSString *xPathLookupQuery = @"//table[1]//tr"; // Path in xml
nodes = PerformXMLXPathQuery(data, xPathLookupQuery); // Pass the data in that you need to search through
[self populateArray:weatherArray fromNodes:nodes]; // To populate multiple values into array.

session = [[self fetchContent:nodes] retain]; // To populate a single value and returns value.

- (void)populateArray:(NSMutableArray *)array fromNodes:(NSArray *)nodes 
{
for (NSDictionary *node in nodes) {
    for (id key in node) {
        if ([key isEqualToString:@"nodeContent"]) {
            [array addObject:[node objectForKey:key]];
        }
    }
}
}
```

You only need either the above code or below code unless you want both.

```
- (NSString *)fetchContent:(NSArray *)nodes 
{
NSString *result = @"";
for (NSDictionary *node in nodes) {
    for (id key in node) {
        if([key isEqualToString:@"nodeContent"]) {
            result = [node objectForKey:key];
        }
    }
}
return result;
}
```